# Dijkstra Correctness

Tags: graph-theory

I have problem proving the correctness of Dijkstra's algorithm.

You can read about the proof here:

http://serverbob.3x.ro/IA/DDU0150.html

I have following two doubts about the following argument:

But because both vertices u and y were in V - S when u was chosen in line 5, we have d[u] ≤ d[y].? 
1. How do we know that when both u and y was in set V-S the vertex chosen is u and not y? We know by our construction that when both u and y are in V−S, then y will be chosen before u. 
2. Where is the fact that node u when added to set S, it is not at the minimum distance from start node s utilized in the proof?
Please help

Answer (score 1):

1. We do not know by our construction that when both $u$ and $y$ are in $V-S$ $y$ will be chosen before $u$ because our weights are not required to be strictly positive only nonnegative. That means some weights could be $0$ and so it could be that $d[u] = d[y]$. Suppose that $d[u] = d[y]$, then $u$ and $y$ have the same priority so they are served according to their order in the queue.

We started the proof by contradiction by supposing that at the current step in the algorithm, it is $u$ that is chosen meaning that $d[u]$ is the minimum element out of all the $d[v]$ for $v \in V-S$ when $u$ is selected. There could be other vertices $v \in V-S$ when $u$ is chosen such that $d[v] = d[u]$ and hence $d[v] \leq d[u]$. In this case, it means that out of all such $v$, $u$ is the element frontmost in the queue (for FIFO).

What you've noticed is that it is impossible that $d[y] < d[u]$ when $u$ is chosen (since it is deduced that $y$ is also in $V-S$ when $u$ is chosen).

2. It is first found that $d[y] = \delta(s,y)$, $d[y] = d[u]$, and that $y$ is contained on a shortest path from $s$ to $u$. Since $y$ is contained in a shortest path from $s$ to $u$ the subpath from $s$ to $y$ (contained in the shortest path from $s$ to $u$ we are looking at) is a shortest path from $s$ to $y$ and hence $\delta(s,y) \leq \delta(s,u)$. From which it follows that $d[u] = d[y] = \delta(s,y) \leq \delta(s,u) \leq d[u]$ and so $d[u] = \delta(s,u)$. It is at this point that we utilize  the fact that node $u$ when added to set $S$ is not at the minimum distance from start node $s$. We have just found that $d[u] = \delta(s,u)$ but we assumed at the start that this was not the case, a contradiction.